# wp_enqueue_script('jquery') does not load jQuery in WordPress 4.9.5?

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
// Adding CSS and JS files
function add_theme_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), '3.0.6', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), '4.1.4', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array ( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
?>
```

All scripts and CSS files are loaded properly except jQuery.  But wp_enqueue_script('jquery') worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress by default register jquery for you but if you like to re-enqueue it then here is a code for it

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_jquery');
function enqueue_script_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

you can also enqueue different version of jquery but it is better to de-register other versions to avoid conflicts

for other version do like this in the function above

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_jquery');
    function enqueue_script_jquery() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js', array(), null, true);
   }
```

Comment: The first snippet does not add jQuery to web pages. But the second snippet has added jQuery to wordpress pages.

Comment: @Anisur then there must some issue on your Wordpress site because normally that code works but anyways now your code is working from the second snippet?